# Is it possible to automatically aggregate data in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a collection where every element has its own counter (a numeric value). Is it possible for Firebase to automatically aggregate (reduce) this data into a single value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server-side (ie. "firebase-side") the answer is **no**.
if your app is simpler/not-secured,  you'd do that client side..   but I guess it's not the case.
Assuming your app's data is fragmented and secured,   you'd normally do this calculation on **your** server (which is itself, a firebase-client), and push this piece of data back to firebase.