# Intersection in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Please consider the following data structure in firebase:

```
products
  + p1
    +name
    +tags
      +t1
      +t2
  + p2 (similar to p1 above)
tags
  +t1
    +p1 (p1 is the product-id) 
    +p2
  +t2
    p3
    p1
  +t3
    p4
    p2
```

I understand that if I wanted to query products by tag - the above structure would be useful (`ref /tags/$tag`) will get me the list of the products.

However, how do I implement / query for intersection of two or more tags? I am open to modifying the data structure to the do this in the best way.

So what I really want to query (and therefore store data) for is the query

```
get products that match tags 1, tags 2 and tags 3
```

Would I need to "run my own server" to do this?
[Is it possible to automatically aggregate data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969525/is-it-possible-to-automatically-aggregate-data-in-firebase)

Comment: There is no method for automatically aggregating data. You would perform a separate query based on each tag and join the results by hand.

Comment: Thanks @Kato! So just read the last X list from each part and manually filter / sort it in js! Is there a recommended "aggregation" / sort /filter js lib that works well with firebase or processing like these?

Comment: Firebase-util works fairly adequately. It will have a new release within the month which will be a great deal more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait some more time as Client side joining and and intersection are introduced in the Firebase Developer Summit 2016, it's documentations and tutorials will be available soon.