# How to do Mathematical Operation in Firebase like SQL/PL?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a Android application that send location via webserivce to server(MySQL) it will calculate the user location(Longitude,latitude) and location(Longitude,latitude) in the DB with the Help of the Query with math function(Like http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html)  in the MySQL but in the Firebase database how do I do the same in the Firebase ?

Comment: The Firebase Database does not have support for such server-side aggregation operations. The GeoFire library (through the "magic" of GeoHashes) is able to do GeoQueries, but that's about as advanced as it gets. I'll post a few related questions below...

Comment: [Do some work on the data on firebase database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766240/do-some-work-on-the-data-on-firebase-database/37766303#37766303), [Sum firebase data efficiently up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838059/sum-firebase-data-efficiently-up/37838387#37838387), [Server Side Calculation using Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643147/server-side-calculation-using-firebase/33652773#33652773)

Comment: **Super Thanks Buddy**